# Compilation error when importing a non-standard dependency into a Rust library

Tags: rust, dependencies

I am currently trying to build a small **Rust** library which is callable from **Python** (via the magic of `ctypes`). I succeeded in making a "Hello, world!"-level function and importing it into Python, but ran into difficulty when I tried to add another layer of complexity by adding a prime-finding function, which makes use of `primes` - outside the Rust standard library. In short, if I run `cargo build`, then I get the following compilation error:

```
  --> src/lib.rs:10:5
   |
10 | use primes;
   |     ^^^^^^ no `primes` in the root
```

### Rust Package Structure

The structure of my Rust package is very straightforward:

```
|__src
|    |__lib.rs
|__Cargo.toml
```

### Code

I thought it might be helpful to show you what the code in this little package looks like.

#### `Cargo.toml`

```ini
[package]
name = "hosker_primes"
version = "1.0.0"
authors = ["Tom Hosker"]

[lib]
name = "primes_lib"
crate-type = ["dylib"]

[dependencies]
primes = "0.3.0"
```

#### `src/lib.rs`

```rust
use std::ffi::CStr;
use std::os::raw::c_char;
use std::os::raw::c_int;
use std::str;

use primes;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", _find_nth_prime(3));
}

fn _find_nth_prime(n: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut count = 0;
    let mut current = 0;

    while count < n {
        current += 1;

        if primes::is_prime(current) {
            count += 1;
        }
    }

    return current as i32;
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn make_contact(c_string_ptr: *const c_char) {
    let bytes = unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(c_string_ptr).to_bytes() };
    let silly_word = str::from_utf8(bytes).unwrap();

    println!("Congratulations! You have made contact with the PRIMES library.");
    println!("This is the silly word you gave me: {}", silly_word);
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn find_nth_prime(c_int_ptr: *const c_int) -> *const c_int {
    let int_ptr = unsafe { c_int_ptr.as_ref().unwrap() };
    let result = _find_nth_prime(*int_ptr) as *const c_int;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @PitaJ That's disappointing. Forgive my scepticism, but are you sure you've constructed your package exactly as I have? In particular, are you sure that you've included a `lib.rs` file and NOT a `main.rs`, and have you included the `dylib` stuff in your `Cargo.toml`?

Comment: @PitaJ I suspect you may have unconsciously added a missing line while attempting to reproduce my issue. See my answer below.

Comment: ot: `use primes;` is a no-op (aside from failing to compile when there is no crate or module `primes`, but if you use it at all, that will suffice as well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, however:

1. I discovered it purely by luck, and
2. **I have no idea why it works.**

It seems that, if I add the following line to the `package` section of my `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
edition = "2021"
```

then everything just works!

Is this perhaps a failure of the Cargo interface? Would it not be more helpful if the user was alerted to the missing field, rather than some weird import issue flaring up further down the line?

Comment: For compatibility reasons Rust uses edition 2015 by default if you don't specify an explicit edition in your `Cargo.toml`. In edition 2015, external crates needed to be declared as `extern crate primes;` in `main.rs` or `lib.rs`.

Comment: Note that if you create a new project with `cargo new`, it will automatically add the latest `edition` in the generated `Cargo.toml`.

Comment: This is documented in more details in the [editions guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/edition-guide/rust-2018/path-changes.html#no-more-extern-crate)